# How to process / summarise a list into a "different" list

Tags: haskell, fold

I think I need something like a fold or maybe a foldt but the examples I've seen, seem to only compress the list into a simple scalar value.

What I need would need to remember and re-use values from previous lines in the list (essentially a "group by" operation)

If my input data looks like:
    `[["order1", "item1"],["", "item2"],["","item3"],["order2","item4"]]`

What is the correct approach to end up with something like:

`[["order1",["item1","item2","item3"]],["order2",["item4"]]`

ie `data Order = Order { id :: Text, items :: [OrderItem]}`

What if I wanted a slightly different structure?

`[("order1",["item1","item2","item3"]),("order",["item4"])]`

ie `data OrderTuple = OrderTuple { order :: Order, items :: [OrderItem]}`

What if I also wanted to keep a running total of some numeric value from the OrderItem?

edit: Here's the code I'm trying to get working based on Frerich's answer

```
--testGroupBy :: [[String]] -> [[String]]
testGroupBy :: [[String]] -> [(String, [String])]
testGroupBy z = 
  --groupBy (\(x:xs) (y:ys) -> x == y || null y) z
  groupBy testFunc z

testFunc :: [String] -> [String] -> Bool
testFunc (x:xs) (y:ys) = x == y || null y
```

Comment: google (without much luck) with folds looking something like the best bet.

Comment: These inputs look kind of strange. Where are they coming from?

Comment: the input is a (simplified for this question) version of csv export of customer orders from ebay. each line in the csv represents an order item. on orders with multiple items, some of the fields are left blank for the subsequent items. (very mundane I'm afraid :) )

Comment: @Simon, if I were dealing with this sort of thing, the very first thing I would do would be to `map` over the fields and change the fields that are allowed to be *missing* from `String` to `Maybe String`. This separates the syntactic expression of missingness from its semantic model. Afterwards, you can deal with the *interpretation* of missingness as a direction to fill in the blank in a certain way.

Answer (score 2):

Pattern matching is useful here

```
groupData = foldl acc []
            where acc ((r, rs):rss) ("":xs)   = (r, rs ++ xs): rss
                  acc rss           (x:xs)    = (x, xs): rss
                  acc _             _         = error "Bad input data"
```

resultant groups are in reverse order, use `reverse` if you need.

*What if I wanted a slightly different structure?*

Simply transform one into other, you can do inside `groupData` or as separated function.

If you admit initial groups without `fst` element

```
groupData = foldr acc []
            where acc (x:xs)   []             = [(x, xs)]
                  acc ("":xs)  (("", rs):rss) = ("", rs ++ xs): rss
                  acc (x:xs)   (("", rs):rss) = (x, rs ++ xs): rss
                  acc (x:xs)   rss            = (x, xs): rss
```

then

```
let xs = [["", "item8"],["", "item9"],["order1", "item1"],["", "item2"],["","item3"],["order2","item4"]]
print $ groupData xs
```

is

```
[("",["item9","item8"])
,("order1",["item3","item2","item1"])
,("order2",["item4"])]
```

Comment: That's brilliant, thank you :).

Now I just need to think through *why* it works :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looking for a `fold`-based solution, I'd first try to see whether you can define a function as a composition of higher-level functions (such as `map`). Let me fire up a `ghci` session and play abit:

```
λ: let x = [["order1", "item1"],["", "item2"],["","item3"],["order2","item4"]]
```

Your "group by" operation actually has an existing name: [`Data.List.groupBy`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Data-List.html#v:groupBy) -- this almost gets us what we need:

```
λ: import Data.List
λ: let x' = groupBy (\(x:xs) (y:ys) -> x == y || null y) x
λ: x'
[[["order1","item1"],["","item2"],["","item3"]],[["order2","item4"]]]
```

This `groupBy` application puts all elements in `x` into one group (i.e. list) whose first element is equal, or if the second element is empty. This can then get massaged into your desired format (in this case, the second one you proposed with a `map`):

```
λ: let x'' = map (\x -> (head (head x), map (!! 1) x)) x'
λ: x''
[("order1",["item1","item2","item3"]),("order2",["item4"])]
```

Putting it all together:

```
groupData :: [[String]] -> [(String, [String])]
groupData = map (\x -> (head (head x), map (!! 1) x))
          . groupBy (\(x:xs) (y:ys) -> x == y || y == "")
```

I suppose that with this, building a proper data structure (i.e. something more typesafe than nested lists) should be straightforward.

Comment: Frustratingly, this works perfectly if I cut/paste straight into ghci but almost identical code fails to compile if I try to incorporate it into a simple test program. (I've added my test code to the bottom of my original question)

Comment: OK, I've realised my mistake. The type signature of testGroupBy should be `[[String]] -> [(String, [String])]`